# Data gathering from multiple branches to one headquarter database

Tags: c#, sql-server, polling

I'm building a POS system. I want to have a branch-headquarter system where a branch can have 1 local server and many clients, headquarter can have 1 local server and many branches.

For a branch, I could simply change the connection string of clients and it will not become a big issue as the max number of clients is around 10.

For headquarter, it could have many branches. The local server at branch will send it's data to headquarter's database. Here's is the part I am confused.

If I just change the connection string which contains headquarter's address, port, and database name, it doesn't look secure enough. If anyone knows the connection string, he/she can open management studio and connect to the headquarter's database directly.

In order to gather branch database data into headquarter's database, how can I achieve this? I just want to be pointed to the right direction.

I have searched and created server-client socket program to exchange data but there are too many potential risks (if socket program crashes, I would need to keep monitoring to see if it's running, etc)

Please share me some good ideas!

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to aggregate data from multiple branches into a central headquarters database, you should perhaps look into Microsoft Sync Framework. That's what it's designed to do.

If you want to do other things (for instance if the branches have to be able to access headquarters data on demand) then consider using a secured Web API to expose the functionality you need to the branches.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't put it in the question but I have already looked into MSF and I was very disappointed that I was not able to control it the way I want. For example, if I change the design of a table, I will need to do de-provision and provision again but this process will not work properly and it would need to upload all of the data from the beginning.